# SimpleDateFormat ParseException in some devices

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat, parseexception

I'm parsing a backoffice date (C#) `\\/Date\\((\\d+)([-+]\\d+)?\\)\\/` with `org.joda.time.DateTime`

Example:
1 - BO date = **/Date(1380891215020+0100)/**
2 - DateTime BO date parsed = **2013-10-04T12:53:35.020+01:00**
3 - Calendar.setTime(DateTime BO date parsed) = **Fri Oct 04 12:53:35 GMT+01:00 2013**
4 - String finalDate = Calendar.getTime().toString(); = **Fri Oct 04 12:53:35 GMT+01:00 2013**

At this point everything went ok. Now I want to make a date comparison so:

```
Date dateA = mySimpleDateFormat.parse(finalDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateA);
...
```

When I use `mySimpeDateFormat` to parse `finalDate` in some devices a

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Oct 04 12:53:35 WEST
>   2013" (at offset 20)"

is thrown. **HTC One S** is one of that devices.

Phone Date & Time settings:
- Automatic date & time: true
- Automatic time zone: false

Any idea why is there WEST instead of GMT+01:00?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!
First of all thank you for your answers.

I forgot to say that my Locale was Locale.ENGLISH but the problem wasn't there, it was on step 4:

```
String finalDate  = mySimpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getTime());
```

instead of

```
String finalDate = Calendar.getTime().toString();
```

Now I always have a date format like **Fri Oct 04 12:53:35 GMT+01:00 2013** and everything works just fine ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Device locale (deals with language and time) could be the problem. the finalDate string obviously is a timestamp in English, you device might not be.

Answer (score 1):

I have been through similar problem. Use `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);` instead. On some devices locale is not US and `Calendar.getInstance()` return `Calendar` in some other locale. Same goes for `SimpleDateFormat`, try using `mySimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);`.